# Tricky foreach loop... how to?

Tags: php

I am looping through a spreadsheet which may have information like so:

```
To                  From
LAX/SAF/ORL         ORL/SAF
LAX/DUB             DUB/SAF
SAF/LON             LON/BNE/SYD
```

I need to loop through this info so I get something like so:

```
Result 1: Lax -> Orl
Result 2: Lax -> Saf
Result 3: Saf -> Orl
Result 4: Saf -> Saf
Result 5: Orl -> Orl
Result 6: Orl -> Saf
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
$row = "LAX/SAF/ORL";
$row2 = "ORL/SFO";
preg_match_all('([A-Za-z]+)', $row, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $location_to){
    echo $location_to . " -> " . $row2 . "<br />"; //currently doesn't loop through row2
}
```

How can I do this but for both sets of data? I'm currently stuck how to kind of.. foreach twice like above to get the output I need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated (This needs to run through one loop as it is a row on a spreadsheet and has other assigned data to it).

It's basically a multi trip entry sort of thing.

Thanks

Comment: shouldn't $row be $col?

Comment: Latox - `preg_match` is inefficient for this purpose (though I gather you know that from the answers by now ^^).  @user1389596 really?  Going to argue semantics and variable naming?  If you want to be technical, it would be a 'field', not a column.  Be constructive with what you post.

Comment: @Jon it wasn't clear to me if these were really alternating lines of data.

Comment: This is also called the Cartesian product of two sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you have, try:

```
$row = "LAX/SAF/ORL";
$row2 = "ORL/SFO";
$arow = explode("/", $row);
$arow2 = explode("/", $row2);
foreach($arow as $p1) {
    foreach($arow2 as $p2) {
        echo "$p1 -> $p2 <br>";
    }
}
```

And that will create the type of output you are looking for since you already know what `$row` and `$row2` are ^^

Answer (score 1):

1. If its s spreadsheet read it as CSV if you can
2. why regex? jsut explode on `/`

So then something like this:

```
$file = fopen('/path/to/file.csv', 'r');
// skip headers
fseek($file, 1);

while($row = fgetcsv($file)) {
   $from = explode('/', $row[0]);
   $to = explode('/', $row[1]);

   foreach($from as $i => $sender) {
      $recipient = isset($to[$i]) ? $to[$i] : 'undefined';
      echo "$sender -> $recipient";
   }  
}
```

Comment: Just up voted to thank you for your time & to get rid of that dirty down vote!

Answer (score 1):

You're actually fairly close. I would do it as such:

```
$row = "LAX/SAF/ORL";
$row2 = "ORL/SFO";
$from = explode('/', $row);
$to   = explode('/', $row2);

foreach ($from as $f){
    foreach($to as $t) {
        echo $f . " -> " . $t . "<br />";
    }
}
```

EDIT: You may want to add a check for `if ($f == $t)`, because ORL -> ORL doesn't really make sense. :)

Comment: Yeah ORL -> ORL is fine, it is flight locations. I will give this a go now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested foreach and loop over the $row2 matches, like so:

```
$row = "LAX/SAF/ORL";
$row2 = "ORL/SFO";
$to_locations = explode('/', $row);
$from_locations = explode('/', $row2);
foreach ($to_locations as $to){
  foreach ($from_locations as $from) {
    echo $to . " -> " . $from . "<br />";
  }
}
```

Comment: I literally just copied what the OP had. I'm working on improving it at the moment.

Comment: Someone is a little trigger happy on the down votes this evening.. i put in my two bullets, saved and then began editing to drop in the code example and by the time i saved again i had a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$row = "LAX/SAF/ORL";
$row2 = "ORL/SFO";

$rows = array($row, $row2);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    preg_match_all('([A-Za-z]+)', $row, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[0] as $location_to){
        echo $location_to . " -> " . $row2 . "<br />"; //currently doesn't loop through row2
    }
}
```

Basically, the code you had will execute for each element in the `$rows` array.

In the future, if you have more rows (i.e., each line of a file), you just add them to the `$rows` array, and the code will loop through each row.

Comment: Don't use `preg_match` for this.  It is completely inefficient for this purpose.

Comment: I built upon the code in the question, you should post your comment on the question instead

Comment: True, you built upon the code in the question, but you just 'made it work' rather than improving it.  And while that comment does also belong on the question, every answer that uses the same method deserves the same comment. ;)

Comment: I agree with you, actually I'm upvoting your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = "LAX/SAF/ORL";
$row2 = "ORL/SFO";
$first_array = explode('/', $row);
$second_array = explode('/', $row2);
$result_array = array();
$assoc_array = array();
foreach($first_array as $value1) {
  foreach($second_array as $value2) {
    $assoc_array[$value1] = $value2;
    $result_array[] = $value1.' -> '.$value2;
  }
}
```

And this will lead you to have either an associated array, if you wish that, or an array which will have strings in the form LAX -> ORL